# What is going wrong in my hangman program?

Tags: python-3.x, debugging

I'm trying to get a function to put correct guesses in their blanks in a hangman program, but all it does is, whatever the guess and no matter whether it's right or wrong, it just gradually reveals the word. Where am I going wrong?

code:

```
while lettersrevealed!=word:
    guess=getGuess(lettersrevealed)
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if guess in word:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + word[i] + blanks[i+1:]
            print(blanks)
```

ex:
 (secret word is badger)

```
Guess a letter:  
a  
b*****  
ba****  
bad***  
badg**  
badge*  
badger  
Guess a letter:  
OR:  
Guess a letter:  
h  
b*****  
ba****  
bad***  
badg**  
badge*  
badger  
Guess a letter:
```

Comment: What is the value of `guess`? I would guess that it doesn't contain what you think it contains. And also `if 'a' in 'badger'`, as in your first example, is true for every single character in `word` - `if guess == word[i]` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the for loop

```
for i in range(len(word)): # This will run 6 times for "badger" | 0, 1, .., 5
    if guess in word:
# blanks == ****** then gradually gets the next letter added replacing a * 
        blanks = blanks[:i] + word[i] + blanks[i+1:]
        print(blanks)
```

You probably want something like this.

```
def convert_to_blanks(word, letters):
    return ''.join(c if c in letters else '*' for c in word) 

>>> word = 'badger'
>>> letters = set()
>>> convert_to_blanks(word, letters)
'******'
>>> letters.add('g')
>>> letters
{'g'}
>>> convert_to_blanks(word, letters)
'***g**'
```

And so you have a while loop prompting for letter something like this.

```
guessed = set()
word = 'badger'
while True:
    guess = input("Guess a letter")
    guessed.add(guess)
    blanks = convert_to_blanks(word, guessed)
    print(blanks)
    if blanks == word:
        break
```